# Import data from an URL with quotes using google sheets

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using a script called "ImportJSON" created by paulgambill https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164

My URL has quotes char
Example
`http://SomeAPIULR?{"Type": "SomeType"}&APIKEY=key`

When I remove from the URL {"Type": "SomeType"} the script works perfect

```
function ImportJSONAdvanced(url, query, options, includeFunc, transformFunc) {
  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL);
  var object   = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());

  return parseJSONObject_(object, query, options, includeFunc, transformFunc);
}
```

Any how to make this work?

Comment: Thanks for your response but looks like the client side doesn't support the encoded conversion

Comment: also what error are you getting?

Comment: It's not clear how are you passing your URL to `UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL)`. Is URL a variable or just a placeholder for `http://SomeAPIULR?{"Type": "SomeType"}&APIKEY=key`?

Comment: I passing the URL directly from Google Sheet =ImportJSON(yourURL,query)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to do it Using encodeURI().

Thanks everyone for the comments!